# Unable to upload actual file to target using CURL

Tags: curl, libcurl, perfecto

I am using CURL commands in shell script file to download .apk file from one place and load it to another

```
wget -c https://example.net -O abc.apk

source="abc.apk"
dest="abc.apk"
securityToken="Actual Token"
url="https://another.com/services/repositories/GROUP:abc/${dest}?operation=upload&securityToken=${securityToken}&overwrite=true)"
curl -X POST -T "$source" "$url"
```

But I am not getting any error and even file is not getting uploaded.

When I run from VM I get:

> {"errorMessage":"Failed to upload repository item - Value true) for overwrite parameter is not a valid boolean value."}

Note: Target URL is the Perfecto URL.

Comment: There is a trailing `)` behind the `url`. `&overwrite=true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our Perfecto curl documentation is [here](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/How+to+upload+file+to+the+repository+via+API+using+postman+or+curl).

I was able to upload a sample apk file with curl as follows:

```
curl -X POST -T "abc.apk" "https://${CLOUD_NAME}.perfectomobile.com/services/repositories/media/PRIVATE:abc/abc.apk?operation=upload&securityToken=${YOUR-SECURITY-TOKEN}&overwrite=true"
```

Note: CLOUD_NAME is your exact cloud name. E.g. demo is the cloud name of https://demo.perfectomobile.com cloud url.

Kindly raise a support case by following [here](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Opening+a+Ticket+with+Perfecto+Support) in case you get any issues with curl/ any Perfecto questions in general.